# How to reclaim unoccupied disk space with Disk Utility?

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro which I tried to set up for dual-booting OS X and Linux. It resulted in some unclaimed free space on my SSD, see screenshot below.

Unfortunately, I am unable to reclaim that free space: It is grayed out and there seems to be nothing in Disk Utility that I can use to change that.

[image]

Comment: BEFORE TRYING ANYTHING, READ THIS: I've had the same issue, and getting rid of it messed up my Mac partition. Make sure to backup any important data. I went into recovery mode to get rid of it (since I couldn't get rid of it in Mac), so I would suggest not going in recovery mode to get rid of it. You'll probably have to use some Terminal commands.

Comment: @FlareCat the only reason why it would mess up your partition is if you tried to merge your OS X partition *with* your free space. If you had merged your free space *with* your OS X partition, it wouldn't have erased data. Merging erases the data of the partition to be merged into the base partition.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry I didn't try to merge it, all the data was still there, but unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the screenshot you posted. "To resize a partition on the selected disk, drag its resize control and click Apply." You should be able to just increase the size of the Macintosh HD partition to use the free space. I would recommend backing up first to be safe.